# Access variable in recursive for loop

Tags: php, recursion

I have an tree of objects (All is in PHP).

I want to run through it recursive. In the recursive function is a loop. I want to access an variable given by the previous call, but I can't. I can access the variable outside the loop:

```
protected function saveTree($tree, $fk=null)
{
    echo $fk; //this works
    $objects = $tree->getChildren();
    for($i=0; $i<count($objects); $i++) 
    {
        echo $fk; //don't work
        //...
        $this->saveTree($objects[$i], $id);  
    }
}
```

How can I access the $fk variable?

Edit:

Here are my "Tree-Classes"

```
abstract class Element
{
    protected $name;
    protected $parentNode;
    protected $object; 
    protected $dbId;

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parentNode;
    }

    public function setParentNode($parentNode)
    {
        $this->parentNode = $parentNode;
    } 

    public function getObject()
    {
        return $this->object;
    }

    public function setObject($object)
    {
        $this->object = $object;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getDbId() 
    {
        return $this->dbId;
    }

    public function setDbId($dbId)
    {
        $this->dbId = $dbId;
    }

    public function  setData($data) {
        $this->object->exchangeArray($data);
    }
}

class Node extends Element 
{    
    protected $children = array();

    function __construct($parentNode)
    {
        $this->parentNode = $parentNode;
    }

    public function pushChild($child)
    {
        if($child) {
            array_push($this->children, $child);
        }
    }

    public function getChildren() 
    {
        return $this->children;
    }
}
```

Here is the full recursive method:

```
protected function saveTree($tree, $fk=null)
{

    $objects = $tree->getChildren();
    echo count($objects); //This works
    echo $fk; //This works also
    for($i=0; $i<count($objects); $i++) 
    {
        echo 'test'; //this works
        echo $fk; //this doesn't work


        $parent = $objects[$i]->getParent();
        $config = $this->getConfig();
        $table = array_search($objects[$i]->getName(), $config); 

        $objects[$i]->getObject()->setChildren($objects[$i]->getChildren());

        $objects[$i]->setObject($table->save($objects[$i]->getObject()));

        if($objects[$i]->getObject()) {
            //the condition is tested and in every test-case true
            $id = $objects[$i]->getObject()->getId();
            $objects[$i]->setDbId($id);

            echo $id; //this works
        }
        $this->saveTree($objects[$i], $id);  
    }    
}
```

With foreach is it the same problem:

```
//...
echo $fk; //work
foreach($tree->getChildren() as $object) 
{
    echo $fk; //don't work
    //...
```

Comment: What do you mean, *access an variable given by the previous call*? The scope of the variable is local so unless you overwrite it, the variable will be the same before and in the loop.

Comment: This is the point I don't understand. I can echo the value of $fk in the line before the for(...), but two lines under the value of $fk is null.

Answer (score 1):

`count($objects)` returns `0`, so PHP never enters the loop, that's why `$fk` is never being echo'd more than once.

Comment: I have checked it. This is unfortunately not the answer. When I echo the count of Objects i always get a number more then 0. I can also echo an static value (for example echo 'test';) in the loop and this will be printet.

Comment: @ThomasDeniffel: can you post the full code of the `saveTree` function then?